# Validations for api build with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Person`.

One controller `Api::V1::PersonsController`

In my controller:

```
def index
  @persons = Person.new(user_id: @current_user.id, type_id: params[:type_id]).method
  render json: @persons, status: :ok
end
```

In my model:

```
attr_accessor :user_id, :type_id
validates_presence_of :type_id
```

Also tried:

```
validates :type_id, :presence => true
```

When I create my Person with no type_id, I don't get any error, what else do I need to do, or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.new` is not going to persist your Person to the database.

Validation will not be carried out unless using `.save` after `.new` or in a `.create` or `.create!` method.

[Check out point 1.2 here in Rails validation guides ›](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Comment: Could I also suggest moving this code from an index method to a create method in the person controller? This would a better suited place for this action and free's up your index method for other logic like list all persons.

Answer (score 3):

From the Rails guide [validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) section:

> The following methods trigger validations, and will save the object to
> the database only if the object is valid:
>
> create
> create!
> save
> save!
> update
> update!
>
> The bang versions (e.g. save!) raise an exception if the record is
> invalid. The non-bang versions don't, save and update return false,
> create just returns the object.

When you create an object using the `new` method, the validation rules do not fire as the object is not persisted to the database.

You can call `Person.save` or `Person.save!` after `Person.new` or create a `Person` object using `create` or `create!`. Both of these methods persist the object to the database so a validation error will be raised.

Also, in your case, you can do something like this:

```
Person.new(user_id: @current_user.id, type_id: params[:type_id]).valid? # => false
```

This way, you can check if the object is a valid object and then proceed with the rest of your code.